# Noisy HP DL360 server and DMESG errors

Tags: bios, fan, acpi, hp-proliant

I purchased a HP ProLiant DL360 server for use with Solaris testing because it was OEM hardware. The server sits in my basement and its kind of noisy. It sounds like a mini [high-bypass jet engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbofan), even when there's no load on it.

The dmesg log is below. The one that caught my eye is ***`SpeedStep support is being disabled due to errors parsing ACPI P-state objects exported by BIOS`***. I seem to recall a Debian or Ubuntu error report about HP Proliants and a ACPI or BIOS bug.

I thought I could update the BIOS to clear it. The installed BIOS is dated 2011, and there's a new BIOS dated OCT 2015. Unfortunately, [HP has the bug fixes behind a Paywall](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3288144) - they want me to pay to fix their defective product!!!

Solaris is fully patched and up to date. The HP product page did not list the server as *End of Life* and it included a field for the warranty (though it did not specify what the warranty was). I joined the HP Passport program, and the *"Entitled Download"* effectively changed to *"Service Contract Required"*.

My question is, what can I do to fix this issue (short of paying the extortion or the ransom)?

---

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i '(warn|err)'
Jun  9 16:32:40 solaris unix: [ID 388705 kern.info] NOTICE: cpu_acpi: error parsing _PSS for CPU 3
Jun  9 16:32:40 solaris unix: [ID 928200 kern.info] NOTICE: SpeedStep support is being disabled due to errors parsing ACPI P-state objects exported by BIOS.
Jun  9 16:32:52 solaris bnx: [ID 565147 kern.warning] WARNING: bnx1: Failed to initialize default MSIX isr handle block (-4)
Jun  9 16:32:52 solaris bnx: [ID 260081 kern.warning] WARNING: bnx1: Reverting to Fixed level interrupts
Jun  9 16:32:52 solaris bnx: [ID 565147 kern.warning] WARNING: bnx0: Failed to initialize default MSIX isr handle block (-4)
Jun  9 16:32:52 solaris bnx: [ID 260081 kern.warning] WARNING: bnx0: Reverting to Fixed level interrupts
Jun  9 16:33:06 solaris unix: [ID 954099 kern.info] NOTICE: IRQ18 is being shared by drivers with different interrupt levels.
Jun  9 16:33:08 solaris unix: [ID 954099 kern.info] NOTICE: IRQ19 is being shared by drivers with different interrupt levels.
Jun  9 16:33:12 solaris /sbin/dhcpagent[370]: [ID 778557 daemon.warning] configure_v4_lease: no IP broadcast specified for net0, making best guess
Jun  9 16:33:24 solaris asr-notify[989]: [ID 555615 daemon.warning] System is not registered with Auto Service Request. Please register system using asradm(1M) or visit http://www.oracle.com/asr for more information.
Jun  9 16:33:42 solaris gdm-simple-greeter[1358]: [ID 702911 daemon.warning] WARNING: Failed to send buffer
Jun  9 16:33:42 solaris gdm-simple-greeter[1358]: [ID 702911 daemon.warning] atk-bridge-WARNING: AT_SPI_REGISTRY was not started at session startup.
```

Comment: I have the 2011 BIOS and my HP DL360 G5 is fine so far. Can you check battery on your RAID card?  For noise, perhaps change the power options in the BIOS to Static (low) or OS controlled.

Comment: @Peter - sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure how to check battery status; I'll need to look into it. I can't really dethrottle the machine because its under a fair amount of use. Derating slows performance for everyone and skews benchmark test.